# Angular @Input type accepts faulty model

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to make @Input to my component with a model that looks something like this

```
interface Car {
    sail?: never
    tires: number
    weight: number
}

interface Boat {
    tires?: never
    sail: boolean
    weight: number
}

export type Vehicle = Car | Boat;
```

Goal is to accept inputs like this: (this works and does not give me any error)

```
  @Input() Car: Vehicle = {weight: 2500, tires: 4}
  @Input() Boat: Vehicle = {weight: 2500, sail: true}
```

This gives me error as expected

```
  @Input() Mixed: Vehicle = {weight: 2500, tires: 4, sail: true}
```

And in my html file i have this (should only be able to input tires or sail not booth, should throw error)

```
  <component [car]="{weight: 2500, tires: 4, sail: true}"></component >
```

And the Input from the html file doesn't give me any error as expected from Angular. But what I am not understanding is how the `Vehicle` type can be populated with faulty data. What is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: Did you try with [strict mode](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#strict-mode)?

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML there is no type-checking, since this is specific to Typescript.
However, you can declare the Vehicle in your .ts file and use the variable within your HTML, this way you should get an error as expected.